# Hyperledger sawtooth supply chain

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am trying to modify fish-client property of hyperledger sawtooth.
But the transaction is not getting submitted when I make changes in relevant js file add_fish_form.js,lis_fish.js,etc files

Please have a look in the below url in which you'll find fish-client code:

https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-supply-chain

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! To help others answer your question, consider including the code you have tried so far and the outcome of it, as well as a bit more detail on what behavior you are expecting.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what changes you made. Try running the supply chain application without modifying it. If it works, make small modifications.

Also look at the log file for the REST API and Validator for error and warning messages when you submit a transaction. If you don't have a debug console terminal window open you can look at the log files under `/var/log/sawtooth/`